# Stepwise model selection in an R tidyverse workflow

Tags: r, tidyverse, glm, magrittr

I am trying to use step function for AIC-based model selection in a tidyverse workflow. However, I receive an error:

> Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.' not found.

I need the tidyverse workflow for occasional filtering of the data. What should I do?

```
mean_mpg <- mean(mtcars$mpg)

# creating a new variable that shows that Miles/(US) gallon is greater than the mean or not

mtcars <-
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg_cat = ifelse(mpg > mean_mpg, 1,0))

mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

mtcars_lr <-
  mtcars %>%
  select (cyl,vs, am, mpg_cat) %>%
  glm(formula = mpg_cat ~ cyl+vs+ am,
      data =., family = "binomial")

step(mtcars_lr)
```

Comment: Maybe `mtcars_lr <-
    glm(formula = mpg_cat ~ cyl+vs+ am,
        data = mtcars %>%
            select (cyl,vs, am, mpg_cat), family = "binomial")`

Answer (score 1):

this has to do with the `magrittr` pipe `%>%`. In this [technical note](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) you can find the following paragraph:

> The magrittr pipe operators use non-standard evaluation. They capture
>   their inputs and examines them to figure out how to proceed. First a
>   function is produced from all of the individual right-hand side
>   expressions, and then the result is obtained by applying this function
>   to the left-hand side. For most purposes, one can disregard the subtle
>   aspects of magrittr's evaluation, but some functions may capture their
>   calling environment, and thus using the operators will not be exactly
>   equivalent to the "standard call" without pipe-operators.

This means that very often `x %>% f` is equivalent to `f(x)`. In your case it is not.
You will have to do something like this:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg_cat = if_else(mpg > mean_mpg, 1,0),
         cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
  select (cyl, vs, am, mpg_cat)


glm(formula = mpg_cat ~ cyl + vs + am,
    data = mtcars2, family = "binomial") %>% 
  step(mtcars_lr)
```

To see the difference you can try the following:

```
x1 <- glm(formula = mpg_cat ~ cyl + vs + am,
    data = mtcars2, family = "binomial")

x2 <- mtcars2 %>% glm(formula = mpg_cat ~ cyl + vs + am,
                      data = ., family = "binomial")

all.equal(x1, x2)
[1] "Component “call”: target, current do not match when deparsed"
```

So the call components of `x1` and `x2` are different and the `step` function uses this argument.